# Gitlab CI/CD generic package file expiration time

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

I'm using the Gitlab CI/CD API to upload a zip file containing a built project as a generic package, like this:

```
curl --header “JOB-TOKEN: ${CI_JOB_TOKEN}” --upload-file $OUTPUT_FOLDER/${ZIP_NAME}.zip ${PACKAGE_REGISTRY_URL}/${TAG_NAME}/${ZIP_NAME}-${TAG_NAME}.zip
```

It works and everything, but I'm interested in knowing if the package file has an expiration date (i.e.: if it will be deleted automatically after some time) because I'm not being able to find any reference to that in the docs.
Just if that matters: We are using SaaS Gitlab with a premium account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're uploading this to the package registry, it'll stay there until you `delete` it. This registry is different than the Artifacts system in GitLab CI/CD where it expires. The Infrastructure and Container Registries act the same way as the Packages Registry.